# How to set http headers for MPMoviePlayerViewController content url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http-headers, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play a video from url which need authentication. I tried few example from internet which have used custom NSURLProtocol. But it doesn't work with the custom NSURLProtocol.

Is there any other good way to achieve this?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html
Use AVPlayerViewController